# Optocoupler conducts without LED supply

Tags: arduino

I'm a beginner in electronics. I am trying to use an optocupler (p621) to switch 12v supply to 5v for digital input.

Here is the fritzing diagram

[image]

So from the 12v supply I am using 1 1k resistor into the opto P621. So the LED turns on when the button pressed. Then in theory the 5v from arduino connects to pin 2 as a digital input.

Its working fine without much trouble. But even without Optos LED power, the Opto conducts 5v from arduino to the pin..
I've no idea what happens here.

I checked in serial monitor and it says high for that pin randomnly..

So does opto conducts without led voltage or something else wrong in my circuit??

Schematic View

[image]

Comment: 1. Share the schematics..Clean hand drawn is also okay..  2. enable pullup on Pin 2

Comment: No, a proper schematic, not a cartoon of how you built it.

Comment: What happens if you remove the switch from your breadboard?

Comment: @marcelm it still shows high.. So 5v conducts even without led

Comment: in the answer to your previous question you accepted the answer showing a pulll-up resistor. why do you use pull-down?

Comment: Your schematic is upside down.

Comment: What is the exact voltage at the emitter?

Comment: Maybe a favour to yourself, DO NOT POST FRITZING drawings in EE StackExchange calling it schematic. The chances of receiving an answer will be higher if you keep Fritzing out.

Answer (score 1):

Typically its best to connect the optocoupler in a low side configuration(rather then a high side. The diagram below should help you restructure your circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcOgGO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hopefully this way, the internal transistor inside optoucoupler fully turns on when 12V is available and arduino would get 0V. When 12V is not available, Arduino would get 5V at the input.(You can invert the input in logic for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: Hi friend, I'm not able to locate the difference between this and my version. Sorry I'm a newbie in electronics

Comment: @SandeepThomas The emitter pin is grounded, the resistor is connected on the collector side

Comment: @SandeepThomas A transistor that is NPN should always sync to ground. The TLP621 you are using uses a NPN transistor. (look at the real datasheet : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwibsozI2MvnAhUqwlkKHaj8CycQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftoshiba.semicon-storage.com%2Finfo%2Fdocget.jsp%3Fdid%3D16778%26prodName%3DTLP621&usg=AOvVaw0pnnd4ReUxHMRbKOhh4Oj4  )  If you want to use an active high input on your aduino, then you need to get an optocoupler with a PNP (sourcing) transistor. Or simply add a PNP transistor to your existing circuit.

Comment: @NoumanQaiser Why would it matter? Normally for a NPN transistor switch, you want to connect the emitter voltage to ground because the base voltage is relative to the emitter and if you connect it the other way around, you get an emitter follower instead. With an optoisolator, this is not a reason because there is no base.

Comment: @user253751  Optoisolators are not all reversible. Some use a single PNP or NPN transistor. A NPN transistor can never be used with the emitter to the positive supply. The base is irrelevant.

Comment: @NatsuKage However, it can be used with its *collector* to the positive supply just fine. (Technically also with its emitter to the positive supply, in "reverse active mode", but why would you do that?)